# Error while trying to get tab name

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to get the `datagridview` name on event `tab_SelectedIndexChanged`
as shown below but I am getting error message that says

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'

anyway one can help me

```
    public static string Selected_dgvName;

    private void tab_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Selected_dgvName = tab.TabPages[tab.SelectedIndex].Name;

    }
```

Comment: use Selected_dgvName =  tab.TabPages[tab.SelectedIndex].Name.ToString();

Comment: @EmadDehnavi [`Name` is a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage_properties(v=vs.110).aspx). Something is missing from this question as `TabPages` is a collection of `TabControl`s. `TabControl` derives from `Control` and inherits its `Name` property, a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string Selected_dgvName;

private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Selected_dgvName = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name;
        }
```

can you please check your tab name,